# tail -n 10 is truncating my entire file

Tags: logs, tail, truncate

I have these 2 scripts, one is writing to the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
   sleep 1;
   echo "$(uuidgen)"  >> /tmp/cprev.stdout.log
done;
```

the other is reading the last 10 lines and overwriting the file with those 10 lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
   sleep 5;
   inotifywait -e modify /tmp/cprev.stdout.log | tail /tmp/cprev.stdout.log > /tmp/cprev.stdout.log
done;
```

for some reason the tail command is truncating the file - what I want to do is write to the file only when the tail command finishes getting all 10 lines from the file, how can I do that?

what actually happens:

1. tail truncates file
2. tail reads 0 lines

but what I want to do:

1. tail reads 10 lines
2. tail truncates files
3. tail writes 10 lines from above

how can I do that?

Comment: Hint: `tail` isn't writing to the file, the shell is. And the shell truncates it before `tail` gets a chance to read anything

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
   sleep 5;
   inotifywait -e modify /tmp/cprev.stdout.log | while read line; do
      lines="$(tail /tmp/cprev.stdout.log)"
      echo "$lines" > /tmp/cprev.stdout.log
   done;
done;
```

but I am looking for something sleeker if possible

Comment: only one loop right

Comment: @guest not sure what that is, can you add an answer?

Comment: the first script is a long running process (an agent running on a local laptop) so re-writing the first script as you have is probably a little hard I think, but might work. the reason why it's hard is partially because I don't want to re-write the file on every write to the file.